# Python row major to column major order vector

Tags: python, numpy, row-major-order, column-major-order

Having a matrix like

```
ma = [[0.343, 0.351, 0.306], [0.145, 0.368, 0.487]]
```

I want to get a vector like:

```
[0.343, 0.145, 0.351, 0.368, 0.306, 0.487]
```

To try to get it, I am using `numpy` and `reshape` but it is not working.

```
a = np.array(ma)
>>> print a.shape
(2, 3)
```

But I am getting:

```
c = a.reshape(3, 2, order='F')
>>> print c
array([[ 0.343,  0.368],
       [ 0.145,  0.306],
       [ 0.351,  0.487]])
```

What would be the best way to do it for any matrix size? I mean, for example, if matrix is not squared like:

```
[[0.404, 0.571, 0.025],
 [0.076, 0.694, 0.230],
 [0.606, 0.333, 0.061],
 [0.595, 0.267, 0.138]]
```

I would like to get:

```
[0.404, 0.076, 0.606, 0.595, 0.571, 0.694, 0.333, 0.267, 0.025, 0.230, 0.061, 0.138]
```

Comment: Why would you tell Python to reshape your array to 3-by-2 if you want a shape of `(6,)`?

Comment: I was doing some tests, but still not get the shape I want, to, and also How can I tell python to get the size (in example  is 3,2) and then do shape (3*2) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`ravel()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) to flatten the array.

```
>>> a.T.ravel()
array([ 0.343,  0.145,  0.351,  0.368,  0.306,  0.487])

# Or specify Fortran order.
>>> a.ravel('F')
array([ 0.343,  0.145,  0.351,  0.368,  0.306,  0.487])

a = np.random.rand(4,2)
>>> a
array([[ 0.59507926,  0.25011282],
       [ 0.68171766,  0.41653172],
       [ 0.83888691,  0.22479481],
       [ 0.04540208,  0.23490886]])

>>> a.T.ravel()  # or a.ravel('F')
array([ 0.59507926,  0.68171766,  0.83888691,  0.04540208,  0.25011282,
        0.41653172,  0.22479481,  0.23490886])
```

Comment: What the heck? That actually seems to work, but it's completely contrary to how the documentation says `ravel` takes arguments. Is this an undocumented feature? Or a bug?

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html shows the `order` parameter, as does the doc string for the method `a.ravel([order])`.  Was this added in a newish release?

Comment: It is in the Numpy 1.3 documents (v1.9 is current), although the order options has expanded beyond `C` and `F`.  There are now the `A` and `k` options (see docs for details).

Comment: @hpaulj: My comment was regarding an earlier version of the answer, which provided `[3, 2]` as the `order` argument.

Comment: That was a silent error (the argument was ignored because it didn't match one of the four options).

Answer (score 5):

You can get want you want by transposing the matrix and then using [numpy's ravel function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
mat = np.random.rand(3,2)
print np.ravel(mat.T)
```

Answer (score 4):

Flatten the array in Fortran order:

```
c = a.flatten(order='F')
```

You could also get the results you wanted with `reshape`, but it's wordier:

```
c = a.reshape(a.size, order='F')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> A = ([[0, 1, 2],
...        [3, 4, 5],
...        [6, 7, 8]])
>>> 
>>> print(A)
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
>>> 
>>> [y  for x in [[row[i] for row in A] for i in range(len(A[0]))] for y in x]
[0, 3, 6, 1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8]
>>> 
>>>
```

Comment: what if the list is flat not two dimensional ?